# Doctrine, symfony forms: could I explicity set id to any document

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, doctrine-odm

So, for example, I get some document, set to him id and image and save it in next way:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager')

$seoBlock = $dm->getRepository('AppBundle:SeoBlock')->find(367);
$seoBlock->setId(366)->setImages(['someUrl']); // 366 is already exist
$dm->flush($seoBlock);
```

After this I don't discover the updated seoBlock with `id: 366` (updated images). Instead of this I see the `id: 365` updated seoBlock.

So the question: can I change the id in some way and update exactly `id: 366` seoBlock if I explicity set Id?

**UPDATE**

`why don't you just find that and simply update it's images property?`

I have symfony form which have next structure:

```
"hotelname",
"countOfRooms",
...,
director: { // here is example with data
   "id": 15
   "firstName": "John"
   "lastName": "Johansson",
   "born": "1975-10-19"
}
```

And I request this as `json`. So want to change director not only name or lastname, but entire director. This could be provided by director option `'by_reference' => false`, BUT!

I want go have possibility to make request with e.g. only `id` and `firstName` and if `id = 16`, director for this hotel become with 16 and its `firstName` would be changed. Thats what I want.

By reference say me that I set entire object, so If I request just part of data it gives missed data from previous object and save it. That is, e.g.,

`id: 15, firstName: 'Nikolay'`, `id: 16, firstName: Erick`. If director was with id: 15 and I request next:

```
director: {
    id: 16,
    lastName: "Kolesov"
    // and don't point the firstName
}
```

doctrine write to the database firstName to `id: 16` Nikolay.

So, the conclusion: I want to break in somehow reference *director* form *hotel* and set new Id, and doctrine have to get the object with *new Id*, take new changes and, **for id which I pointed in the request**, not which was in the document(or entity - doesn't matter) before submit, and update the object (with `id: 16`).

P.S.: now I solved this problem by listener which find object by director id and set the entire object hotel, and then form submit necessary changes to needle director.

Comment: If `366` already exists (like you state in the code comment), why don't you just find that and simply update it's `images` property?

Comment: see UPDATE section

Comment: I wrote so many, but it doesn't matter. I just want to know could I or not.